# How can I select all the text on a line without the indentation in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to replace all the text of the current line under the cursor and `c`hange the text so I start typing the new code. But I want to keep the indentation.

Currently I am using `ddO`. This will delete the line and open a line before the cursor in insert mode, it's good because vim will take notice of the previous indentation and place the cursor as expected.
But I want to use `c` similar to `ciw` (change inner word) because it feels natural to think "change the line". `Vc` is almost what I want but it will lose the indentation.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `cc`?

```
:h cc
```

> ["x]cc  Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
>               insert |linewise|.  If 'autoindent' is on, preserve
>               the indent of the first line.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am quite new to vim and also I didn't know we could search information using `:h`. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (to put in your vimrc):

```
:onoremap ii :<c-u>normal! v^o$h<cr>
:xnoremap ii ^o$h
```

- The first line defines the mapping `ii` which will work with any command expecting a motion (`cii`, `dii`, `yii`...).
- The second mapping allows to use it in visual mode (e.g., `vii`).

Brief explanation of the `:normal!` command:

- `v` : visual mode, `^` : go to 1st non-blank char, `o` : go to the opposite side of the selection, `$h` : go past to the end of line then go 1 char left.